# Equivalent Excel Macro to C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have a Excel Macro that I'm trying to translate to C#, but i don't know how to translate this part:

```
Dim Files As Variant
Dim glos As Integer
Dim Sheet1 As Object
Dim Un As Workbook

Files = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", 2, "Open Files", , True)
If IsArray(Files) Then
    'Something with some data
    For y = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
        Workbooks.Open Files(y)
        b = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        glos =  glos + 1
        For Each Sheet1 In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet1.Copy after:= Un.Sheets(Un.Sheets.Count)
        Next
        Workbooks(b).Close False
    Next
End IF
```

I have tried some methods, but doesn't work, well I have this so far in C#:

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook oWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

dynamic Files = oWb.Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", 2, "Select Files", Type.Missing, true);
if (Files is Array)
{
    //Something with some data
    Array ar = (Array)((object)Files);
    for(int y = ar.GetLowerBound(1); y < ar.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
    {
        oWB.Application.Workbooks.Open(ar[y]);
        b = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name;
        glos += 1;
        foreach(Excel.Sheets Sheet1 in excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets)
        { 
            Sheet1.Copy(After: Un.Sheets[Un.Sheets.Count]);
        }
        ExcelApp.Workbooks[b].Close(false);
    }
}
```

I have been trying to improve my skills translating some macros that I use in my work to C# but I get stuck in this one, sorry for the bad english, I'm still learning the language.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  Are you getting any error messages?  What are they?  On which line of code are you getting these error messages?

Comment: yeah, you're right, sorry, I get the code error "Cannot apply indenxing with [] to an expression of type 'Array' "

Comment: On the line _oWb.Application.Workbooks.Open(ar[y]);_

Comment: Isn't `Files` already an array?  You tested for that in `if (Files is Array)`.  So you shouldn't need all those casts in `Array ar = (Array)((object)Files);`

Comment: Why are you using the Excel `GetOpenFilename` method?  Is there a reason not to use the native .NET tooling for that?

Comment: Yes, `Files` is an array but without that cast I get the error code _Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[*]' to type 'System.Object[]'._

Comment: `Array` in C# is not an array in VBA: use ar.GetValue(y).ToString();

Answer (score 0):

An `Array` is a special type of class in C# and is not the same as a VBA array. If you use `Array`, then you need to address an individual element like this:

```
ar.GetValue(y).ToString();
```

More information on the Array class can be found in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation. C# does have the concept of an array - note the non-capitalization. It is declared more like this:

```
string[] ar = new string[iNumberOfMembers];
```

And that can be addressed using `ar[y]`